# WhereUsedFilterData using coreservice throwing exception

Tags: 2011, core-service

I am trying to get whereUsed data of a component/page template ? It throws the below fault exception.

"Cannot create an abstract class."

```
       WhereUsedFilterData usingItemsFilterData = new WhereUsedFilterData ();           
       return  client.GetListXml(tcmID, usingItemsFilterData);
```

Is there any other alternative way to get the whereUsed or Is there any problem in my code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than using the base class `WhereUsedFilterData` you should use on of the derived classes `UsedItemsFilterData` or `UsingItemsFilterData` like below:

```
//Get all items using the given TCM ID
UsingItemsFilterData usingItemsFilterData = new UsingItemsFilterData();
return client.GetListXml(tcmID, usingItemsFilterData);

//Get all items used by the given TCM ID
UsedItemsFilterData usedItemsFilterData = new UsedItemsFilterData();
return client.GetListXml(tcmID, usedItemsFilterData);
```